# pgAdmin4 can not connect to postgres server though the password is correct?

Tags: postgresql

I am newbie with pgAdmin4 and here is my problem.

I setup postgresql in ubuntu, everything seems ok, I change password for the account postgres by this command `sudo passwd postgres` and note it very carefully.

Then, I tried to connect to postgresql by pgAdmin4 follow this tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRdl0P4V-PU

Name is localhost
Hostname is localhost
Port is 5432
Maintenance database is postgres
Username is postgres
And password is the password I set above.

But they said to me that `Unable to connect to server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

I tried to change the password, but still the same error. Seems something wrong ?
Could you please give me some ideas ? Thank you very much.

Comment: seems you changed password of os user not PostgreSQL user.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you only changed the password at the OS level.  Basically, for the Ubuntu user `postgres`, you changed the password with `sudo passwd postgres`.

In order to change the password for the `postgres` user for the database, you need to log into the database and change the `postgres` user's password with `ALTER ROLE postgres PASSWORD '<your password>';`

In order to accomplish this, you will need to change your `pg_hba.conf` temporarily, allowing the `postgres` user to log in without a password (either set to `trust` or `peer` authentication method, change the password, and the switch back to `password` or other authentication method).  After changing `pg_hba.conf` you will either want to issue a `kill HUP` to the parent `postgres` process (check the top-most process in your `ps -ef | grep postgres` output), or simply restart postgres with `systemctl restart postgresql<your_postgres_version>`